# PHP Woocomerce get product brand name - short description

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I'm trying to put the tag in the short description of the product, but with the code I'm using the product sku is also showing up, and it's taking the link from the brand.

I just wanted the brand, and when I click go right to her page. what am I doing wrong?

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_short_description', 'single_product_short_description', 10, 1 );
function single_product_short_description( $post_excerpt ){
    global $product;

    if ( is_single( $product->id ) )
        $post_excerpt = '<div class="product-message"><p>' . __( "Vendido e entregue por", "woocommerce" ) . '</p></div>' . $post_excerpt;

    if ( class_exists( 'WooCommerce' ) ) {
        $kode = $product->get_sku();

        $tax = array(
        'Brand:'=>'product_brand',
         );

        foreach ($tax as $mk_label => $mk_value) {
            $make_array = wp_get_post_terms(get_the_ID(), $mk_value, array("fields" => "names"));
            foreach ($make_array as $value) {
                $mk .= $value.", ";
            }
            echo '<strong>'.$mk_label.' <a href="javascript:void(0)">'.rtrim($mk,", ").' '.$kode.'</a></strong>';
            $mk ="";
        }
    }
    return $post_excerpt;
}
```

Comment: Already came with the theme, it's Categories Brand. A Taxonomy.

Comment: Remove the $kode variable in the echo statement to prevent the SKU from showing in the short description.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to take out the SKU, but the link did not yet appear

Comment: Use this to get the product link, $product->get_permalink()

Comment: I want the Brand link.

Comment: I don't know how the theme is storing that information.

Comment: I'm a little lay still. I was able to make the link work by taking a few lines of code. But I'm not getting it again.